# How can i change Only one field value in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a phonebook project I'm trying to make for school.
I want to be able to change a value of a certain field.
I print the field that are changeable. 
before i had `PRIMARY KEY` it changed everyone for example if i changed the name, it would change everyone that is on the list name.
Now I tried to catch a specific one with a id as primary key and it throws this exception:

```
Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).
```

(this code now works if someone will see it in the future :)
I incremented the contactNum in the `editConatct()` to match it with the id field in my MySQL data base )
my edit code:

```
protected void editContawct(){
        System.out.print("Which One You Want To Edit: ");
        ArrayList<String> fields = editContactHelper();
        ArrayList<Person> people = checkMoreThanOne();
        int contactNum = menu(people);
        int option = menu(fields);
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Changes");
        String changes = MyUtills.readStringFromUser();

        String sql = "UPDATE " + DB_NAME + " SET " + fields.get(option) + " = ? WHERE ID = ?";
        try {
            statement = db.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, changes);
            statement.setInt(2,contactNum + 1); //contactNum `incremented to match 'id' field in my MySQL.`
            statement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("worked ?");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //todo add a param that accepts a String that is the data base name.
    private ArrayList<String> editContactHelper(){ // should accept data base name
        ArrayList<String> fieldsName = new ArrayList<>();

        //todo switch the constant to the accepted argument (data base name). so if someone else wants to use this method :)
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + DB_NAME; // should be databaseName;
        try {
            ResultSet resultSet = db.prepareStatement(sql).executeQuery();
            ResultSetMetaData meta = resultSet.getMetaData();

            for (int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                if(meta.getColumnName(i).equals("id")){
                    continue;
                }
                fieldsName.add(meta.getColumnName(i));
            }
            System.out.println("it worked Homie");
            return fieldsName;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `?` is your query should relate to one parameter

But you have a mismatch

```
        statement.setString(1, changes);
        statement.setInt(2,contactNum);
```

as you only have one `?`

Comment: thank you :) i added another '?' and incremented the contactNum by one to match the "id" and it now works!